# What message does pipeTo send on a timeout or other failure?

Tags: akka

In Akka, rather than using onComplete on a future response created with ?, I am trying to use pipeTo because that is supposedly the preferred pattern. However, I don't seem to be receiving any Throwables or Failures when the future times out. What should I expect to receive in my actor if a timeout occurs when using pipeTo? What about when a different exception is thrown?  Example code:

```
class Simple(otherActor : ActorRef) extends Actor{
  def receive = {
     case "some_msg" => {
       val implicit timeout = Timeout(1 seconds)
       val response = otherActor ? "hello" 
       response pipeTo self
     }

     // case ??? // How do I handle timeouts?
  }
}
```

If no message is automatically sent when a timeout occurs, how am I supposed to handle timeouts with pipeTo?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The failure of the future is sent as a `akka.actor.Status.Failure` message containing the exception. The exception for timeout is `akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException`.

Comment: is it possible to get the origin msg from timeout message?

Answer (score 11):

If your example closely matches your actual code, then I'm not sure `pipeTo` is what you want here.  Piping the message back to yourself, to me, does not make too much sense and there are better solutions for a case of an actor sending a message to another actor and then waiting for a response.  First though, let's talk about `pipeTo`.  I think a good example of when to use `pipeTo` is if you had three actors, A, B, and C.  A sends a message to B who in turn sends a message to C and that response from C should be returned to A after B does something else to it first.  In that example, you could do something like this inside of B:

```
val fut = actorC ? someMessage
fut map(someMapFunc) pipeTo sender
```

Here, the `pipeTo` function helps to prevent you from accidentally closing over the mutable `sender` var if you were to instead use something like `onComplete` and respond to the `sender` inside of that callback.

Now, for your case, if you just want A to talk to B and then wait for a response from B (and handle potential timeouts), you could try something like this:

```
class ActorA extends Actor{
  import context._
  val myB = context.actorOf(Props[ActorB])

  def receive = {
    case msg =>
      myB ! msg
      setReceiveTimeout(2 seconds)
      become(waitingForResponse)
  }

  def waitingForResponse:Receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout =>
      println("got a receive timeout")
      cancelReceiveTimeout

    case response =>
      println("got my response back")
      cancelReceiveTimeout
  }

  def cancelReceiveTimeout = setReceiveTimeout(Duration.Undefined) 
}
```

In this example, A starts with a default `receive` partial function.  When it receives a message, it sends another message to B, sets a receive timeout for receiving a response from B and then switches it's `receive` function to something that is specific to waiting for that response from B.  In that new receive function, I could either get my response from B in time or I could get a `ReceiveTimeout`, indicating that I did not get my response in time.  In either case, I cancel my receive timeout because it repeats.

Now this is very simplified, but I was just trying to show one way to do a back-and-forth between two actors, which it seems like your example was showing.

Comment: This answer was helpful and pipeTo may not be best for the situation I described, but I mostly just wanted to know how errors are dealt with when using pipeTo.